# Make Text to Speech in iOS with Vietnamese language

Tags: ios, text-to-speech

I'm using AVSpeech​Synthesizer but it supports only a few languages, not Vietnamese. Is there any way?

I prefer the engine which can use offline and cheap too. Or whatever if there is no other way.

Comment: You can try the Google's `Cloud Speech API`, but I think it's not cheap like you expected.

Comment: Did you mean Google `Translate API`?